# Configuring next.config file

Tags: reactjs, next.js, semantic-ui-react

I am using Next.js and want to add the [react-semantic-ui](https://react.semantic-ui.com), to use one of their login components.

On the front-end I am getting this error:
    Failed to compile

```
./node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

This is the login component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Form, Grid, Header, Image, Message, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const Login = () => (
  /* login JSX markup */
)

export default Login
```

This is my next.config.js

```
  module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
        loader: 'sass-loader!style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
            publicPath: "./",
            outputPath: "static/",
            name: "[name].[ext]"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: [/\.eot$/, /\.ttf$/, /\.svg$/, /\.woff$/, /\.woff2$/],
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
        options: {
          name: '/static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      }
    )
    return config
  }
}

const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS()
```

This is my package.js

```
  {
  "name": "create-next-example-app",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.19",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "next": "^8.0.3",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.86.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

I read somewhere you have to include a `_document.js` in the pages directory.

```
// _document is only rendered on the server side and not on the client side
// Event handlers like onClick can't be added to this file

// ./pages/_document.js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
            <link rel='stylesheet' 
                  href='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css'
            />
        </Head>
        <body className="custom_class">
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Is this really this hard?

**Update**

There is an alternate way of getting this to work.
When you start up your Next app you get a components folder which includes a `head.js` and a `nav.js` file.

The head.js file ultimately is analogous to a `<head></head>` tag in `HTML`. Or I should say that's what the `head.js` compiles to. ANYWAY, you can just add this in there:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css"
/>
```

and that will work.

But like I said you still can't import the modules like so:

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
```

Comment: Does your app compiles normally with CSS that don't have `@import` statements?

Comment: @NinoFiliu It doesn't compile at all....

Comment: The error might be coming from Webpack. Check [this article](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/webpack-loaders-css-and-sass-2cc0079b5b3a) that does a great job at explaining webpack loaders - what the are, why they are needed and how to use them. In your case, your error looks like Webpack encountered a CSS file but didn't have the required loaders + config to "understand" it.

Comment: @NinoFiliu Thanks my friend, I'll take a look. I bet there is a place somewhere where you have to explicitly configure Webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like I had to do the following to get this to work:

Changing my `next.config.js` file to:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withCSS({
  webpack: function (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 100000,
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    })
    return config
  }
})
```

And doing an `npm i css-loader file-loader url-loader -D` did the trick.

However I'm baffled as to why `css-loader file-loader` are needed? I'm used to webpack configs where you are explicitly adding the loaders (Like we are adding the `url-loader` above)... I didn't have to here!

Answer (score 5):

In case someone uses `next-compose-plugins` and getting the above error, here's a fix:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');

// fix: prevents error when .css files are required by node
if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  require.extensions['.css'] = (file) => {};
}

const nextConfig = {
  target: 'server',
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(raw)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      use: 'raw-loader'
    });

    return config;
  }
};

module.exports = withPlugins([withImages, withCSS({target: 'serverless',
  webpack (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|svg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8192,
          publicPath: '/_next/static/',
          outputPath: 'static/',
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      }
    })
    return config
  }})], nextConfig);
```