# NextJS config - Read json in next.config.js

Tags: javascript, json, next.js

I need to import a local json file to build all the necessary path for an exportpathmap in https://nextjs.org/.

So I need to know, how can I import / require a .json file in the next.config.js file ?

Best Regards

Comment: What is the issue of `require('./path-to-your-file/file.json')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring next.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309300/configuring-next-config-file)